# Finite left/right derivatives imply continuity

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

I have an exercise where I have to give an example, if possible, of a function $f$ which is **not continuous at $x=0$**, but satisfies $f'_l(0)=0$ and $f'_r(0)=2$. Here, we define $$f'_l(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},$$ $$f'_r(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$ Is there such a function? I am trying to find an example but I can not, and I can not write a formal proof either. I know that $f(0)$ has to be $0$ and hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=0,$$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=2.$$ What can I do now? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed to use piece wise functions?

Comment: yes I am! no restriction on what type of function. It is an exercise for 1st year students though

Comment: Next you're supposed to just make a lucky guess. Can you provide an example of $f$ not continuous at $0$ you're already familiar with? (Without any restrictions on derivatives)

Comment: I can always choose two expressions for $f$ (one for $x<0$ and another for $x\geq 0$) and make it discontinuous. That's easy. I just can't satisfy the derivatives.

Comment: Take expression for $x<0$ such that its derivative is always $0$, expression for $x \ge 0$ such that its derivative is always $2$ (with constraint $f(0) = 0$ that would be $2x$).

Comment: Well, that's the trick, sorry for the previous comments. You can't have left and right derivatives without function having left and right limits equal to $f(0)$ - which means continuity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function.

Define $g_l(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{ if }x\leq 0\\f(0)&\text{ if }x>0\end{cases}$. Then $g_l$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and hence continuous. This shows that $f$ is left-continuous at $x=0$.

Similarly, with $g_r(x)=\begin{cases}f(0)&\text{ if }x\geq 0\\2f(x)&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$, $f$ is right-continuous at $x=0$.

---

Alternatively, multiply the lateral limits, in the definition of lateral derivatives, by $x$ and obtain $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)-f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)-f(0)=0$, so $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$ (which does not need to be $0$...)

Comment: This is not sufficient, you need them to be left and right continuous *and have the same limit*.

Comment: @James The left-limit is $g_l(0)=f(0)$, by definition, and the right limit is $g_r(0)=f(0)$, also by definition. I don't see the problem.

Comment: $g_l$ isn't necessarily differentiable at $x=0$ (with any $a$ it isn't even necessarily continuous at $x=0$). $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I am really am having a hard time trying to understand what you are saying. This solution shows that if $f$ is any function for which $f'_l(0)$ and $f'_r(0)$ exist, and are equal to $0$ and $2$, respectivvely, **just as stated in the problem**, then $f$ is continuous at $0$. So there is no function which is **not** continuous at $0$ and has the lateral derivatives...

Comment: What is wrong with the $f$ I give in my answer?

Comment: The right derivative is not 2

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm being silly good call.

Comment: @James Glad I could make my point :)

Comment: This solution uses statement which is outright wrong. As I said, for $f(x) = x$ your $g_l$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$ (for $a \neq 0$ it isn't even continuous). You prove correct fact, but you give incorrect proof.

Comment: @Abstraction But your $f$ does not satisfy the hypothesis $f_l'(0)=0$. God! Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Your statement, as I read it now, is: "For any $f$ such that $f_l'(0)=0, f_r'(0)=2$, defined $g_l$ is differentiable at $x=0$". Is my current understanding correct? If so, take $f(x) = x+|x|, a=1$.

Comment: @Abstraction Where does "$a$" come from? "$a$" is only used when defining lateral derivatives, but in the problem it is clearly stated that we only look at lateral derivatives at $0$. In case $f(x)=x+|x|$ we get $g_l=0$ which is differentiable at $0$, just as stated. Still, there is no problem.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro $a$ comes from *your* definition of $g_l$. For the same $f$, your $g_r = f$ and is not differentiable.

Comment: @Abstraction Now I understand! That was a typo... Thank you very much!